# How to install apps in App Store with a new Apple ID that was already signed in in my new iPad?

Tags: ipad, apple-id

I had buy a new iPad mini 2. The worker of the shop where I bought my iPad was already setting my iPad. He was also created an Apple ID for me. But whenever I want to install any apps, I must enter my password of my Apple ID although I already signed in. Why does this problem happen?

Answer (score 1):

That is normal. Your Apple ID is different from the ID you use to sign in to your iPad. It will always ask for your Apple ID password before a new purchase to make sure that someone else is not purchasing from your account.

If you forgot your Apple ID password, you can reset it at: [https://iforgot.apple.com/](https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid)

Your can change it so that it will not ask you again if you made a purchase within 15 minutes: go to Settings, then 'iTunes & App Store' and then select 'Require After 15 Minutes'.

Comment: I didn't realise that perhaps you do not know the password to your Apple ID - I have added a link to my answer that you can use to reset it.